# Collaborating on a .NET project with a front end developer using a Mac

Tags: .net, windows, macos, development-environment

I'm currently working on a project which requires a .NET back end. I'm on Windows and using Visual Studio 2010.

We're using Subversion for source control.

Here's the problem. I'm the **only person** at my agency using Windows. Everyone else is on a Mac.

How am I able to collaborate on a project with the front end developer if he can't even run the web application locally?

Is there a way to emulate Visual Studio on a Mac?

Do I just have him build out all the HTML, then I would just cut it up into the views/layouts? If there are bugs/tweaks only found out during QA, how would he make changes to his front end code?

Answer (score 0):

The Mac users will need to use something like [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) instead of Visual Studio.

> MonoDevelop is an IDE primarily designed for C# and other .NET languages. MonoDevelop enables developers to quickly write desktop and ASP.NET Web applications on Linux, Windows and Mac OSX. MonoDevelop makes it easy for developers to port .NET applications created with Visual Studio to Linux and to maintain a single code base for all platforms.

Comment: In my experience MonoDevelop just doesn't cut it as far as interop with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have the opposite situation - we're a Microsoft shop, and I use a Mac.

I actually get the best of both because I run Visual Studio (and SQL Server and the rest of the MS stack via Parallels for Mac).  I really love Coherence mode.  It makes it look like I'm running VS directly within the OS X desktop.

Comment: I've had nothing but problems with Parallels. I've used it before and it crashed my Mac on a daily basis.

Comment: @JackMarchetti: That has not been my experience [ 2012 MacBook Pro; Parallels 8 Desktop; Windows 8 virtual machine running in Parallels ].  Perhaps a newer version has fixed the crashes.  BootCamp is always an option.

Comment: I definitely prefer bootcamp. I'm running bootcamp on a Mac Pro desktop. I'm not sure my Mac front end dev knows Windows enough to load up VS and start messing around with it though.

Comment: Its not that difficult.  I'm sure they can figure it out.  Afterall, they have a job in technology.  Google is their friend.  So are you.

Answer (score 0):

> How am I able to collaborate on a project with the front end developer if he can't even run the web application locally?
>
> Is there a way to emulate Visual Studio on a Mac?

Do the front end developers need to only run the web application locally to compile it? If it is former then they don't need to run Visual Studio.

In any case, one recommendation I have is to run a Windows VM on Mac.

Comment: Well they would need to run it locally for testing/debugging wouldn't they?

Comment: To debug their client side, they will need to run it. If they need to debug the server they will  need visual studio. In either case, I think a windows VM running on Mac is the best solution. Wine is also an option, but I don't know how well it run a .net application.